# How to implement handsontable into nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, handsontable

Im trying to install handsontable on my project I use

```
npm install handsontable @handsontable/vue
```

Maybe I need to create a plugin?
How Can I use handsontable in a existign nuxt project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I got success by this. Hope this helps you and save some time.

1. Run `npm install handsontable @handsontable/vue`
2. Create a file name **vue-handsontable.js** under **plugins** directory and put as following.

```
const HotTable = !process.client ? null : require('@handsontable/vue').HotTable
export default HotTable
```

3. Open nuxt.config.js and append following.

```
  build: {
    vendor: ['handsontable'],
  },
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/vue-handsontable', ssr: false },
  ]
```

4. Go to your template file and put lines like this.

```
<template>
  <HotTable :settings="settings" :data="data"></HotTable>
</template>

<script>
  import HotTable from '~/plugins/vue-handsontable'

  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        settings: {
          data: [
            ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
            ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13],
            ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 13],
            ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
          ],
          colHeaders: true,
          rowHeaders: true,
        }
      };
    },
    head: {
      link: [
        { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', 
          href: '/your/path/to/css/directory/handsontable.full.min.css' },
      ]
    },
    components: {
      HotTable
    }
  }
</script>
```

Wish you best of luck.

**REV 1:**

The license key is obligatory since Handsontable 7.0.0 (released in March 2019).

```
settings: {
  data: [
    ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
    ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
  ],
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wondering how to make the `registerAllModules()` work, here's how:

1. Do as the Muhammad Ehsanul Hoque answer
2. Make another plugin for `registerAllModules()`,
   build new file at `/plugin`, `handsontable-regis`

/plugin/handsontable-regis.js

```
    const registerAllModules = !process.client ? null : require('handsontable/registry').registerAllModules
    export default registerAllModules
```

3. Open nuxt.config.js and append following like before

/nuxt.config.js

```
    lugins: [
       { src: '~/plugins/handsontable-regis', mode: 'client' },
    ]
```

4. Then, import and call the function in `activated` live cycle in your template files like this

```
<script>
  import registerAllModules from '~/plugins/handsontable-regis'
  import HotTable from '~/plugins/vue-handsontable'

  export default {
    data: function() {
      return {
        settings: {
          data: [
            ["", "Ford", "Volvo", "Toyota", "Honda"],
            ["2016", 10, 11, 12, 13],
            ["2017", 20, 11, 14, 13],
            ["2018", 30, 15, 12, 13]
          ],
          colHeaders: true,
          rowHeaders: true,
          licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation'
        }
      };
    },
    head: {
      link: [
        { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', 
          href: '/your/path/to/css/directory/handsontable.full.min.css' },
      ]
    },
    components: {
      HotTable
    },
    activated: {
      registerAllModules
  }
  }
</script>
```

Hope you'll find this useful